# Kops / Kubernetes: No context set in kubecfg, name is required

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Someone else in my org did the initial setup Kubernetes setup with Kops on AWS, so we already have the S3 bucket config and the cluster running.

My local env `KOPS_STATE_STORE` is pointing to the previously setup S3 bucket. The `CLUSTER_NAME` env is set to: `[name].k8s.local` since it's a gossip-based cluster.

I'm trying to get kops and kubectl setup locally to work with this pre-made cluster. I have AWS credentials setup, and when i run `kops get cluster` I see `sitenamecom.k8s.local aws us-west-1a`.

When I do `kubectl config get-clusters` or `kubectl config get-contexts` it prints nothing except blank columns.

When I do `kops validate cluster` it says: `root.go:227] no context set in kubecfg  --name is required`

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out, had to run:

```
kops get clusters
```

Next, set the `KOPS_CLUSTER_NAME` variable, if you haven't set it already

```
export KOPS_CLUSTER_NAME=<your_cluster_name>
```

To set the context just run

```
kops export kubecfg
```